# Copying and modifying weights with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to copy weights from one net to another. When I do this, I can see the effect in the target net inside the sacAgent object:

```
sacAgent.actor.latent_pi = copy.deepcopy(pretrained_actor.latent_pi)
```

When I try to copy the weights element-wise like so, I don't see any effect:

```
with th.no_grad():
    for key in sacAgent.actor.latent_pi.state_dict().keys():
        sacAgent.actor.latent_pi.state_dict()[key] = \
            pretrained_actor.latent_pi.state_dict()[key]
```

Edit: I have also tried following guidelines from other posts on adding noise to weights in order to first subtract the initial weights and add in the ones I want to use instead. When I compare the values inside tensors, they seem to match, but the behaviour of the net is different when using the deepcopy approach. I am using it inside stable baselines reinforcement learning framework and the net initialised with deepcopy behaves as expected but the one initialised with the = or add_ operators acts exactly the same as a randomly initialised net would:

```
with th.no_grad():
    for key in sacAgent.actor.latent_pi.state_dict().keys():
        sacAgent.actor.latent_pi.state_dict()[key].add_(
            -sacAgent.actor.latent_pi.state_dict()[key]
            + pretrained_actor.latent_pi.state_dict()[key])
```

I would prefer to use something similar to the second approach because it's a lot more readable and would make it easier for me to ultimately add noise to the weights. Is there any way to achieve what I am attempting to do?

Comment: Can you explain this? `When I compare the values inside tensors, they seem to match, but the behaviour of the net is different when using the deepcopy approach.` Although you are successful to load the weight, does it have a different action?

Comment: Yes. When I then run the training of the RL agent, the one that is initialised with deepcopy starts off by taking reasonable actions but the other one behaves just as if I had used random initalisation.